# PdfMake library in nestjs is giving me a font error

Tags: node.js, pdf, nestjs, buffer, pdfmake

I am trying to create a pdf in nestjs with pdfmake. For some reason I keep getting this error "UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "File 'Roboto-Medium.ttf' not found in virtual file system." Any help would be appreciated. I tried to install the fonts but still doesn’t work.

```
const documentDefinition: any = {
                header: { text: payload.plan_name, alignment: 'center', style: 'header' },
                content: [

                ],
                styles: {
                    header: {
                        fontSize: 18,
                        bold: true,
                        margin: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                    },
                    subheader: {
                        fontSize: 16,
                        bold: true,
                        margin: [0, 10, 0, 5]
                    },
                    tableExample: {
                        margin: [5, 5, 0, 15],
                        padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
                    },
                    tableHeader: {
                        bold: true,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                },
            };
            payload.all_exercises.forEach((item) => {
                const { day, exercises } = item;
                const bodyData: any = [
                    [{ text: 'Name', color: 'white' }, { text: 'Sets', color: 'white' }, { text: 'Reps', color: 'white' }, { text: 'Rest', color: 'white' }],
                ];
                exercises.map((exercise) => {
                    const { exercise_name, sets, reps, rest = '1min', video_link } = exercise;
                    bodyData.push(
                        [{ text: exercise_name, link: video_link, color: 'blue' }, sets, reps, rest]
                    )
                })
                documentDefinition.content.push(
                    { text: day, style: 'header' },
                    {
                        style: 'tableExample',

                        table: {
                            widths: [200, 70, 70, 70],
                            body: bodyData,
                        },
                        layout: layout,
                    })
            });
            const pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition);
            this.logger.log('Initialized pdfMake')

            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                pdf.getBase64(async (data) => {
                    const newPlan = await this.planRepository.save({
                        ...payload,
                        buffer64: data,
                    });
                    return newPlan;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the Roboto fonts to the application and import those fonts into the code and pass them in, like this:

```
const fonts = {
      Roboto: {
        normal: 'src/modules/pdf/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'src/modules/pdf/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: 'src/modules/pdf/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'src/modules/pdf/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf',
      },
    };

    const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
    const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
```